# regex check existence of patterns between two other patterns across multiple lines in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to check if certain patterns exists between two other patterns across multiple lines. Namely in a SIP SDP I would like to know if 'a=recvonly','a=sendonly' or 'a=inactive' exists between two lines beginning with 'm=' or if there isn't a second 'm=' line then until the end of the string ($). 
For example between 'm=audio' and 'm=video' or if no other line beginning with 'm=' exists then until the end, which is an empty line at the bottom.

### Example 1

```
v=0\r$
o=- 1402066778 5 IN IP4 10.1.1.1\r$
c=IN IP4 10.1.1.1\r$
m=audio 2066 RTP/AVP 0 101\r$
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r$
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\r$
a=ptime:20\r$
a=inactive\r$
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 109 34\r$
a=inactive\r$
a=rtpmap:109 H264/90000\r$
a=fmtp:109 profile-level-id=42e01f\r$
$
```

There is a match here!

### Example 2

```
v=0\r$
o=- 1402066778 5 IN IP4 10.1.1.1\r$
c=IN IP4 10.1.1.1\r$
m=audio 2066 RTP/AVP 0 101\r$
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r$
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\r$
a=ptime:20\r$
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 109 34\r$
a=inactive\r$
a=rtpmap:109 H264/90000\r$
a=fmtp:109 profile-level-id=42e01f\r$
$
```

There is no match here

### Example 3

```
v=0\r$
o=- 1402066778 5 IN IP4 10.1.1.1\r$
c=IN IP4 10.130.93.210\r$
m=audio 2066 RTP/AVP 0 101\r$
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r$
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\r$
a=ptime:20\r$
a=recvonly\r$
$
```

There is a match here again

I thought the following should work because '|' is not greedy but it still finds the pattern in Example 2 where it should not since that appears below the m=video.

```
re1way = re.compile(r'm=audio.*?(a=recvonly|a=sendonly|a=inactive).*?[(^m=).*|(^$)]')
```

Where is the flaw in my idea please?

Comment: Do you mean that `a=something` must appear on the line that immediately follows `m=...`? But no, because Example 3 is a match. Why is example 3 a match? I don't understand your requirements. :)

Comment: Example 3 matches because it contains one of the patterns ('a=recvonly') after the 'm=audio' line but before any other 'm=' line or end of string in this case.

Comment: To be perfectly honest I understand why my regex expression does not work. I just do not know how make one which does. I tried various look around patterns too without much success. I am learning regex now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure based on your question exactly what the parameters are here. But given your examples and note that the end of a string is a possible endpoint, let's assume you want to determine whether one of the three "a=" instances you cite appear between the first "m=" and either "m="/end of string in a single string object (rather than identifying multiple instances in a single string object).

In this case, I might recommend the following utilizing the '|' special character in a two-tiered solution (this is for explanatory purposes but you get the idea).  I'm sure you could craft a fairly complicated single-line search with some work, but in terms of readability I think this is easier:

```
a = re.search("m=(.*?)(m=|$)", example, re.DOTALL)
if bool(a) is True:
    ares = a.group()
    aresb = re.search("a=(recvonly|sendonly|inactive)", ares)
    if bool(aresb) is True:
        print("Yes, 'a=' substring found! Matching substring: " + aresb.group())
else:
    print("No initial 'm=' found!")
```

I note that because the standard regular expressions module doesn't support variable length negative lookbehind assertion patterns, trying to use such methods to create a single line to parse for instances where 'm=' appears before the end of the string (e.g. Example 2) will not work.  A multiline solution is best in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a one-liner liner instead of doing the check in multiple steps. Your two solutions seem to work differently. I also used '|' in my attempts for the same reason you mentioned but it failed me. Your one-liner also fails on Example 2. It finds a match through it should not and I do not know why. To stick to m=audio I only changed the initial m= to m=audio. "m=audio(.*?)(a=recvonly|a=sendonly|a=inactive)(.*?)(m=|$)", the same thing in the two-tier solution., which does work.

Comment: By the way your one-liner is pretty similar to mine which also works for Example 1 and 3 but does not for Example 2. That is why I posted the question.

Comment: Ok, here's what I think the problem is w/ the single line - using '|' on Ex. 2 will produce an (undesired) positive match b/c the latter (m=|$) is correctly finding no match for 'm=' in conjunction with the prior capture groups, but it IS finding a match if it considers the entire string '$' (because of course 'a=inactive' does appear prior to the end of the string, thereby satisfying all capture groups).  I believe my second example consisting of a two-line solution is your best bet.  It may be that using two '|' in two capture groups opens the door to too many undesired positives otherwise.